# Python ftplib retrbinary(), files not downloading completely

Tags: python, ftp, ftplib

Code excerpt:

```
file = open("D:\\DownloadFolder\\test.jpg", "wb")
def callback(data):
    file.write(data)

connect.retrbinary('RETR cover.jpg', callback)
print("completed")
```

This script downloads the file `cover.jpg` from my server. The image is returned distorted though (some parts are missing.) Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are writing files, but not closing them. Consider closing the file with `file.close()`:

```
file = open("D:\\DownloadFolder\\test.jpg", "wb")
def callback(data):
    file.write(data)

connect.retrbinary('RETR cover.jpg', callback)
file.close()
```